# Prevent Plugin from loading on 'wp-admin / wp-login'

Tags: plugin-development

I am creating plugin that redirects users UNLESS they are visiting from a specific IP.

Originally I had this code sat in index.php so it would never load on wp-admin, wp-login pages. However since I have moved this code to a plugin it is.

Does anyone know how I can stop the plugin from running while user is on wp-login / wp-admin? I was going to simply check the url for these strings but wondered if there was a 'better practice' method of achieving this.

**Plugin Code:**

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: LSM - Device Detection
 * Plugin URI: http://no_uri
 * Description: Makes use of WURFL API to detect what device a user is on and redirect if needed
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: James Husband
 * Author URI: http://no_uri
 * License: GPL2
*/

    // I DO NOT WANT THE FOLLOWING CODE TO RUN IF USER IS ON WP-ADMIN / WP-LOGIN

  /* Device Redirects */
    $device = getDevice();
    if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] != "IPHIDDEN" and $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] != "IPHIDDEN" and $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != "IPHIDDEN") {
          switch ($device) {
          case TABLET:
              header('Location: http://www.urlhidden.com/tablet/');
              exit;
          break;

          case DESKTOP:
              header('Location: http://www.urlhidden.com/');
              exit;
          break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the following example to stop the code running on `admin` side or on `wp-login.php` page.

```
if ( ! is_admin() || 'wp-login.php' != $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) {
    // Do stuff here. code inside this statement will 
    // not run on wp-admin & login page.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hook your code onto the [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook which is only fired on the front end of a WP site.